# Does the C++ standard guarantee that string literals are stored in the program binary unadulterated?

Tags: c++, standards

For example, if you have a program

```
int main()
{
    const char* str = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

and you compile it, if you search the generated binary for "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", (ignoring issues such as encoding), are you guaranteed to find it, or is it allowable for the compiler to generate code that, for example, allocates heap memory, fills it with '1's using a loop, and then fixes up all references to that string literal to point to the heap memory? (and then ensures that it gets deallocated at the right time, blah blah)

I doubt there's any implementation that actually does this... but would it be standards conforming if it did?

Comment: Nothing guarantees that. The only thing the standard (I'm looking at a 2005 working draft since nobody ain't no money for the textbook...) dictates is the contents of string literals (be they narrow or wide), their type, their storage duration, escape sequences and concatenation of adjacent string literals. See [2.13.4 here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ doesn't have any concept of a "program binary", so the question doesn't really make sense.

The guarantee is that you get all the characters in the string by incrementing and dereferencing the  pointer `str`, i.e. your string is stored contiguously in memory when the program is running.

Comment: And that guarantee is only made *if* you actually do that (or rather that the compiler cannot prove, up to undefined behavior, you didn't do it), by the as-if rule.  What happens when (say) an external program examines the memory of your executable is not defined by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 3):

Binary storage is not impacted by the C++ standard

Answer (score 1):

No, the standard doesn't tell where and how the string literal is stored. That is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Fabrizio What do you mean? It will never be stored in std::vector

Comment: @Fabrizio: They are just arrays. It's like `foo("Hi");` were replaced with `foo(__literal0)`, where `static const char __literal0[] = {'H', 'i', '\0' };`.

Answer (score 1):

That would be up to the compiler and architecture of the computer the code is being compiled for.  The C++ standard does not affect how the code is stored in its binary format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any good reason for a compiler to do that instead of encoding it within the compiled program.